# How to get Facebook post likes?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I Am trying to retrieve FB Post Likes and Reactions using Graph API. The code that I used to retrieve the **'LIKE','LOVE','HAHA'** of a post is shared below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var postID = '';
var access_token = '';
var refreshTime = 1;
var defaultCount = 0;
var reactions = ['LIKE', 'LOVE', 'HAHA'].map(function (e) {
    var code = 'reactions_' + e.toLowerCase();
    return 'reactions.type(' + e + ').limit(0).summary(total_count).as(' + code + ')'
}).join(',');

function refreshCounts() {
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?ids=' + postID + '&fields=' + reactions + '&access_token=' + access_token;
    $.getJSON(url, function(res){
        var v1 = res[postID].reactions_like.summary.total_count;
        var v2 = res[postID].reactions_love.summary.total_count;
        var v3 = res[postID].reactions_haha.summary.total_count;
        $('#counter1').text(v1);
        $('#counter2').text(v2);
        $('#counter3').text(v3);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(refreshCounts, refreshTime * 3000);
    refreshCounts();
});
</script>
```

But the code showing two `{}` instead of the result.

Comment: Test your request in Graph API Explorer, to see if that is a problem with your request in itself, or with your code.

Comment: And btw., I hope you are not actually exposing an access token in client-side code? And of course you will run into the API Rate Limits pretty quickly, if you try to fire that request every 3 seconds ...

Comment: I generated a token from Facebook Developer page and I tried the token with some other methods such as, Getting page like count from my FB Page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you using javascript SDK?

```
                var postID = $('#post_id').val();
                FB.api(
                        '/' + postID + '/',
                        'GET',
                        {
                            "fields": "reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(1).as(like),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(1).as(wow),reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(1).as(sad),reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(1).as(love),reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(1).as(haha),reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(1).as(angry)",
                            "access_token": "token"
                        },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);                     
                    var like_count = response.like.summary.total_count;                       
                    var love_count = response.love.summary.total_count;                      
                    var wow_count = response.wow.summary.total_count;                  
                    var haha_count = response.haha.summary.total_count;                      
                    var sad_count = response.sad.summary.total_count;                      
                    var angry_count = response.angry.summary.total_count;                        
                }
      );
```

This worked for me